# How to say that you have plans to go to the movies tonight?

Tags: future-tense, future-time, will-vs-going-to

How to say that you have plans to go to the movies tonight (but you are not sure yet, maybe you will have a pizza)? I mean there are options:

> **I am going** to the cinema tonight.

*Way too much certainty* in this. For me it means that you have already bought tickets, the least.

> **I am going to go** to the cinema tonight.

Sounds a bit awkward.

> **I will go** to the cinema tonight.

Sounds too formal to me.

Comment: You've used 'cinema' in your examples. You might want to change that to 'movies' as your question uses 'movies'.

Comment: @VarunKN [it's fine; sense #2](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cinema?q=cinema). We don't restrict ourselves to *InE!*

Comment: All seem *quite certain* that you are going to some movie. If you are *not* sure, you *must* include that by putting *probably, may, think, plan* etc words.

Comment: That's an entire different point of discussion. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21694/movies-vs-cinema-vs-theater-whats-the-difference

Comment: If you say these sentences word for word, they do sound formal, or very certain. But at least with the first two, if I heard them said more casually ("I'm goin' to the cinema tonight" or "I'm gonna go to the cinema tonight") they would sound very natural to me, especially if cinema is replaced with movies (but that might just be my regional opinion).

Comment: Try "I may go to the movies tonight" or "I might go to the movies tonight"

Comment: *Cinema* is more UK English  and *the movies* is classic American English, so you not using the same word in the question title and question body is switching gears with no explanation.

Comment: *I might go see a movie tonight.*

Answer (score 14):

> **I am going** to the cinema tonight.

This indeed shows that plans are already made (not necessarily that tickets are bought already, but the speaker is sure that he will end up watching a movie tonight).

> **I will go** to the cinema tonight.

This is not "formal" as you mentioned, but for this scenario rather implies spontaneous decision (the speaker decided that he will go to the cinema just now).

If you want to express uncertainty, you could go with:

> **I am planning to go** to the cinema tonight.
>
> **I'm thinking about going** to the cinema tonight.
>
> **I might go** to the cinema tonight.

Comment: Another option, a bit less uncertain: "I'm probably going to the cinema tonight."

Comment: A shade more uncertainty would be "I **may be** going", similar to **might be**

Comment: @Peter "may" feels a bit more formal than "might", but other than that I agree.

Comment: -1 *I **will go** to the movies (or cinema)* has nothing to do with spontaneity. It expresses the speaker's current resolve to carry out a future action, thus 'a promise'.

Answer (score 6):

A far more casual response could be, "I'm thinking of catching a movie (film, flic, or flick) tonight."

I am Canadian and as such, I  do tend to borrow from the French, hence, flic/flick for film.

Comment: Flick isn't French, it's short for flicker.

Comment: Yeah, well, that's just, like, your opinion, man

Comment: The French for "film", is "film"...

Comment: Frankly (which is franchement, in French) "flic" actually means "police", in a casual way.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply say:

> I have plans to go to the movies tonight.

Plans are plans, not cast in stone, and are implicitly subject to change. You nailed the answer in your question.

Comment: Slightly alternatively, I usually say "I *intend* to go..." if I've gotten as far as the planning phase (e.g. looking up times, finding something interesting, checking my financial situation, etc). I'm not sure if that's me, or something regional, but I consider it to be a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering based on common, informal speech. Not necessarily proper, well structured English.

> "I think I'm gonna go to the movies tonight.
>
> "I think I'm gonna go to the movies."

In the second example, it's okay to drop "tonight" because it's just common and expected that you'll be seeing a movie in the evening.

> "I think I'm gonna go see a movie."
>
> "I might go to the movies."

It's my experience (Canada) that this type of speech is more common. You rarely ever hear people say theater or cinema in this context. Typically people will use "movie" or "movies" when describing the act of going to the theater to see a movie, because they're describing the event rather than the location or venue.

Where you will hear people use theater/cinema is in speech directly associated with the location rather than the event.

On the phone, Jane asks Jim where he is. He replies:

> "I'm at the theater."

.. rather than:

> "I'm at the movies".

... although it would be perfectly acceptable in informal speech and convey the same meaning to use the latter. Again, to illustrate the point about location versus event:

> Jane: "Where did you get those cool 3D glasses?"
>   Jim:  "At the theater."

Or

> Jane: "Can you grab me a pack of smokes on your way to the theater?"

Jane is a terrible chain smoker and soon she will suffer a premature hypothetical death and no longer be used in my examples.

Comment: I would eschew gonna here.